# How do I decode a list of base64-encoded file names?

Tags: bash, xargs, echo, base64

I have a list of base64-encoded file names in the pattern of `{base64-encoded part here}_2015-11-12.pdf`.  I'm trying to decode that list of files and return it on the command line as another list, separated by newlines.  Here's what I'm trying now:

```
find . -name "*_*" -printf "%f\0" | sed 's/_....-..-..\.pdf//g' | xargs -0 -i echo "{}" | base64 -d
```

I think what I'm doing here is . . .

1. finding the files, printing out only the file's name (i.e., stripping off the "./" prefix) separated by a null character
2. using sed to preserve only the base64-encoded part (i.e., removing the `_2015-11-12.pdf` part of the file's name)
3. using xargs to ostensibly pass each file name to echo
4. then decoding the value returned by echo.

The result of that is apparently a big string of all of the base64-decoded file names, each name separated by a null character, with the entire string followed by a newline.  The *desired* result would be each individual decoded file name on a line by itself.

I've tried all kinds of tricks to try and fix this but I haven't found anything that works.  I've tried `... | base64 -d | echo`, `... | base64 -d && echo`, etc., trying to insert a newline at various points along the way.  It seems like by the time the values end up at `| base64 -d`, they are all processed at once, as a single string.  I'm trying to find a way to send each value to `base64 -d` one at a time, NOT as a monolithic list of file names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the base64 encoding of newline (`Cg==`) after each file name and pipe the whole thing to `base64 -d`:

```
find . -name "*_*" -printf "%f\n" |
  sed -n 's/_....-..-..\.pdf$/Cg==/p' |
  base64 -d
```

With your approach, that would have to be something like:

```
find . -name "*_*" -printf "%f\0" |
  sed -zn 's/_....-..-..\.pdf$//p' |
  xargs -r0 sh -c '
    for i do
      echo "$i" | base64 -d
    done' sh
```

as you need a shell to create those pipelines. But that would mean running several commands per file which would be quite inefficient.

Comment: Nice. Nearly same idea, but you did it better than me!

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to encode `\n` in base64 ... so it becomes `Cg==` this you can append to the printf-command. A '\' cannot be in a filename. So in the end you can sed it back

`find . -name "*_*" -printf "%f\0Cg==" | sed 's/_....-..-..\.pdf//g' | xargs -0 -i echo "{}" | base64 -d | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`

Comment: `XG4=` encodes `\n` as two separate characters, which is `\\n` once escaped. `Cg==` is the right base64 encoding for a newline character (ASCII 0x0A).

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a nifty here-document `<<<`, that will let you pipe multiple lines using xargs.

```
❯ echo -e "T0sK\nT0sK" | xargs -n1 bash -c 'base64 -d <<< $1' _
OK
OK
```

Comment: Never embed `{}` in the *code* argument of the shell (or any interpreter for that  matters), that introduces a command injection vulnerability.

Comment: You're using `\0` for `find` and `xargs`, but `sed` processes `\n` delimited records.

Comment: In the last example, you're using `{}` but not `-I`

Comment: `-i` is equivalent to `-I{}`?

Comment: The null delimiter was from the original example. I've removed it because it's not necessary to illustrate the example.